# Responsive Design, device-height

Tags: css, responsive-design

I am maaking a responsive app for all devices(sizes), I used the formula, target / context = result. For width i given 93.75% (900/960), when i used the same formula for height - 62.5% its not visible, If i used 600px for height that maincontent div is visible, how to fix this ?

Below is my code i tried,

```
<div class="maincontent"></div>

.maincontent{
width:93.75%;/*900/960*/
margin:5% 3.125%; /*30/960*/ 
height:62.5%;/*600*/
background:#2c3e50;
}
```

Comment: I have no idea what you're trying to do, but you're doing it wrong. What do you need the page to look like? At what height do you need to modify the page at?

Comment: i want to  make responsive, width and height does'nt matters, it should adapt to all sizes. . . for ex 1280*800, 800*1280, 1024*600, 720*1280, 540*960, 600*900, 320*480 etc . . .

check out my app link - http://dgcalc.comli.com/

Answer (score 2):

I think you're putting a lot more work into this than you need to, here's how I would set up your calculator:

http://jsfiddle.net/TTQ4e/1/

Working with percentages can get messy real quick - notice how the only percent I use is 100%.

You can make a div visible after a certain height by doing something like this

```
.myDiv {
    display:none;
}

@media (max-height:600px) {
    .myDiv {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

**edit**

Also, the only handheld resolutions you should really worry about are these:

320x480

480x320

360x640

640x360

768x1024

1024x768

800x1280

1280x800

Comment: In fact you don't even need to use 100%. A `block` element has an implied `width` of 100%. As for `height: 100%`, I can't think of any scenario when you wouldn't want the content to decide the height anyways, especially so in responsive design. I'll never understand why people seem to think that responsive design = using percentages all over the place.